# Refresh window in loop

Tags: xcode, cocoa, loops, window, refresh

I have an application written in xcode/cocoa on Mac.
A label on the main window is changed in every occurrence of a heavy loop with [label setStringValue], however it is refreshed only at the end of the loop.
How can I have it refreshed in each occurrence ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a queue. Your heavy loop in *backgroundQueue* and [label setStringValue] in *mainQueue*.

Example:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = 
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();


dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^{
//Your loop

    dispatch_async(mainQueue,^{
    //Set Label value
    });

});
```

Comment: NSAutoreleasePool is not a solution for blocking the main runloop! The solution is to have a new thread to do the work (the loop) and to update the label on the main runloop.

Comment: I sad so too.. with queque.. look at this! "And You also can use a queue. Your heavy loop in backgroundQueue and [label setStringValue] in mainQueue, should work."

Comment: You said "You should use NSAutoreleasePool" and that's wrong as an answer to his question. "And you can also use a queue" is only your second hint and not very strong.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out tonight ! Just a quick question. The dispatch_aync(mainQueue) should be in my loop or after my loop ? I believe in...

Comment: Should be in Your loop, just like in my example which I wrote.

Comment: Quick additional question: I want to pause the background_queue using dispatch_suspend(backgroundQueue), but it doesn't stop. What should I use there ? Thanks.

Comment: And why You need to pause the backgroundQueue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you do the work (the loop) on the main thread. The main thread is responsible for updating the UI and must not be blocked!

You need to start a new thread to do the heavy work and update your UI on the main thread.

You should have a look at GCD which is a good an lightweight solution for that or have a look at the performSelector... methods.